# iPhone Google sheets button

Tags: iphone, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google scripts, so I'm sure this is a simple question.  I have a script that is linked to a button.  It works fine on my PC, but when I push the button on my iPhone, it just selects the button but does not push it.  What am I missing?  If this is a limitation, what would be the best workaround, given that the script just verifies that all cells in the form are complete and adds it to a database?

Answer (score 0):

google apps script interface elements inside sheets do not work from mobile browsers, as of 2016-09. look into building a mobile add-on, which google recently enabled.